# Porcentagem de voto em php dentro de uma while

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso pegar os votos dos candidatos que estão no mysql e gerar a porcentagem de votos que cada um teve.
Como posso visualizar o resultado já que está dentro de uma while?

```
$sql =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM candidatos ORDER BY nome_candidato");
while($ca = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$id_candidato = $ca['id_candidato'];
$nome_candidato = $ca['nome_candidato'];
$votos = $ca['votos'];
}
```

Comment: O que vem dentro de `$ca['votos']` ? Como está estruturada a tabela `candidatos` ?

Comment: $votos = num de eleitores que votaram no candidato

Comment: A tabela está bem simples... id, nome_candidato, e votos... só isso.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode mudar seu SELECT para fazer isso automaticamente. Veja:

```
SELECT id_candidato, nome_candidato, votos, votos * 100 / t.s AS `total`
FROM candidatos
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(votos) AS s FROM candidatos) t ORDER BY nome_candidato
```

[Veja funcionando](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81da0/2/0)

Depois é só usar:

```
$id_candidato = $ca['id_candidato'];
$nome_candidato = $ca['nome_candidato'];
$votos = $ca['votos'];
$total = $ca['total'];
```

Seu código ficará assim:

```
$sql =  mysql_query("SELECT id_candidato, nome_candidato, votos, votos * 100 / t.s AS `total`
FROM candidatos
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(votos) AS s FROM candidatos) t ORDER BY nome_candidato");
while($ca = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
   $id_candidato = $ca['id_candidato'];
   $nome_candidato = $ca['nome_candidato'];
   $votos = $ca['votos'];
   $total = $ca['total'];
}
```

Comment: Aproveite, e inclua também o `order` para coincidir com a pergunta

Comment: @Isac obrigado!

Comment: Ficou perfeito!!

Comment: Muito obrigado à todos!

Comment: @AndréMonjardim não esquece de aprovar

Answer (score 1):

Você já tem a quantidade de votos de cada um, agora some essas quantidades para saber o toral e descubra a porcentagem:

```
$sql =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM candidatos ORDER BY nome_candidato");

$total = 0;
while($ca = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $id_candidato = $ca['id_candidato'];
    $nome_candidato = $ca['nome_candidato'];
    $votos = $ca['votos'];
    $total += $ca['votos'];
}
```

Quando for mostrar os resultados faça o calculo:

```
$umporcento = $total / 100;

$porcentagem = $umporcento * $votos;
```

Comment: Eu também tinha pensado em fazer assim! =) Dá certo também.

Comment: Mas é mais linhas. É questão de aonde quer deixar o trabalho, banco ou PHP

Comment: Exato! Eu particularmente prefiro com o banco. Só não o faço quando não consigo.

Comment: Sempre que posso deixo essa parte para o front-end (javascript)

Comment: Também é uma boa!

Comment: Ficou perfeito com a ajuda de vocês!! Valeu mesmo!